# Is there a way to use a global babel config in all my personal projects?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

Copying and pasting the same config file to every project I create is annoying.

Comment: Using a global config is fine if you're only doing local development, but make sure you include a local `.babelrc` if you check your code into source control.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [from the documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/):

> Babel will look for a `.babelrc` in the current directory of the file
>   being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the
>   directory tree until it finds either a `.babelrc`, or a `package.json`
>   with a `"babel": {}` hash within.

So put it in a higher-level directory, like your home folder.